# DRF Authtoken issues after user model changes

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

After updating the user model to allow for a user profile I have not been able to log in users from the front end.  I can create users with profiles and auth tokens in admin.
Please help.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles.Profile'

DJOSER = {
    # 'LOGIN_FIELD': 'username',
    'SERIALIZERS': {
    'user_create': 'profiles.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'user': 'profiles.serializers.UserSerializer'
    }
}
```

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to ='uploads/profile_pics',default='uploads/default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.avatar.path)
```

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
avatar = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Profile       
    fields = "__all__"
```

class ProfileAvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Profile       
    fields = ("avatar", )
```

class ProfileStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
user_profile = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = ProfileStatus       
    fields = "__all__"
```

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('profile', 'username', 'password', 'id')


def update(self, instance, validated_data):

   if 'profile' in validated_data:
        nested_serializer = self.fields['profile']
        nested_instance = instance.profile
        nested_data = validated_data.pop('profile')

        # Runs the update on whatever serializer the nested data belongs to
        nested_serializer.update(nested_instance, nested_data)

    # Runs the original parent update(), since the nested fields were
    # "popped" out of the data
        return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add more details as to what errors you are seeing when attempting to log in. It is unclear from the given description.

Comment: ```non_field_errors: Unable to log in with provided credentials.```

Comment: It looks like you have changed the Django SECRET KEYS in settings. It happened to me once I changed it then I was not able to login with the given credential because login internally uses secret for creating password hash and if you change it then the hash generated after modification will be different than the one save in db before modification.

Comment: Update - I have added the word 'password' to the DJOSER Dict {LOGIN_FIELD} and now I can authenticate users and sign in but I have now lost my user profile fields in DRF API